# SVN Checkout skipping folders in between

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a directory structure on svn like the following:

- trunk

  - Folder A

    - trunk

      - Folder A Contents
    - tags
    - branches
  - Folder B

    - trunk

      - Folder B Contents
    - tags
    - branches

I would like to checkout of only the root trunk folder, but ignore all trunk/branches/tags folders in between.

So Basically I want to end up with the following structure on Checkout:

- root

  - Folder A

    - Folder A Contents
  - Folder B

    - Folder B Contents

Keep in mind that this is a simplified example, and the directory structure I'm working on is much more complicated, with different levels of 'trunks' everywhere.

Is there an out of the box way to do this in svn/TortoiseSVN? Or should I rely on a script to do this perhaps.

Comment: do you want to automate this or to do it manually? If the later, you could just create the folder structure you would like and then checkout "repo\trunk\FolderA\trunk\FolderAContents" and "repo\trunk\FolderB\trunk\FolderBContents". So basically, just create several checkouts for each directory that you would like to have

Answer (score 0):

So I at least found a way to do this manually, but its the best I came up with.

I first do a checkout of the complete directory structure, as shown on the first part of the question.

After this, I go into each folder that contains a trunk/tags/branches structure and do an SVN Switch using TortoiseSVN, and point to the trunk contents.

For this to work, I need to select the 'Ignore Ancestry' option.